# Was it ever common to carry backup flintlock pistols into battle?

Tags: weapons, 17th-century

I've been replaying Assassin's Creed IV: Black Flag recently and I noticed part of the game's progression involves carrying more and more pistols on your character. At the game's highest tier, having eight flintlock pistols in my inventory. I thought this impractical at first, until realizing the utility of not needing to reload nearly as frequently.

I can find a few references [saying the famous pirate Blackbeard carried six pistols](https://www.quora.com/How-often-would-individuals-carry-multiple-flintlock-pistols-on-them-in-the-18th-century)  but it is unclear if using this many guns was the exception or the rule. While the Blackbeard's armaments were quite well documented elsewhere, the answers regarding cavalry in the same time period don't have any references.

During the late 1600's was it common for people to carry more than one pistol when expecting to battle?

Comment: When you ask about how common it was are you referring to pirates specifically or to any military/naval personnel?

Comment: That's a good question. I've updated the post to remove tags about Pirates. I'm interested in any any military personnel from the 17th century.

Comment: Cavalry performing the [*caracole*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caracole) definitely carried two pistols - but more would have been redundant as the point was to perform the caracole both in unison as a unit and tightly packed for defense. The whole notion strikes me as more appropriate for a *charismatic leader* (ie Blackbeard, as you mentioned) than for formed and trained units.

Comment: Polish hussars could also carry two pistols into battle.

Comment: Done? Yes. Common? The average foot soldier would not be equipped with multiple (expensive) weapons, and could not be expected to fight "tooth and nail" as such use of multiple weapons would indicate in the first place. So we're looking at "uncommon" use cases from the get-go... I feel that the question therefore needs to be a bit more specific on what is expected from an answer.

Comment: IIRC, backup flintlocks could not be carried loaded & primed, so I'm not sure what the utility would be. In a non-naval context, I suspect that the opponent could close to within melee range before the third pistol could be brought to bear.  (and I'm not sure you can see anything at all after firing the second.)

Comment: google "multi barrel flintlock pistol" and you get even crazier things.  you can even buy cute things: https://www.militaryheritage.com/pistol16.htm  But I doubt they could be common. At least carrying 2 double-barreled would be more practical than carrying 4 single barreled.

Comment: If you feel this kind of setup was uncommon feel free to post it as an answer. I'm basing my experience off a video game. It would be no surprise at all to find not true to life

Comment: Bandits in Catalonia aprox. 1550 to 1650 used multiple flint guns, as many as they could, to ambush carriages, including the carriages with gold (soldier's pay) that were sent from Madrid to Italy, and then north, to pay Spanish soldiers fighting in the war of independence of the Netherlands.

Comment: The 1719 novel _Robinson Crusoe_ has several instances of carrying multiple pistols, both on the deserted island, and after Crusoe's return to Europe.

Comment: @PausePause: Again, what is your definition of "common"? "People" did not carry firearms. Regular soldiers would be carrying a musket *and no pistol at all*. Officers would be carrying *a* pistol, So what is the group of people we are looking at to determine common / not common? Pirates? Firearms on ships were under lock, and passed out when battle was imminent. You might *want* to grab an armful of pistols, but I doubt the next crewman would be impressed when he only got a cutlass. So... pirate captains / officers? Those were hardly "common". What is the question?

Comment: I don't know, man. There are 700+ other questions on this site [which contain the word "Common"](https://history.stackexchange.com/search?q=Common+is%3Aq). I didn't think I needed to define that word. Honestly, I feel like half of these comments would suffice as a standalone answer, especially the one regarding the Caracole

Comment: If you google for "pistol pair flintlock" you will find many hits for, specifically, *matched pairs*.  So I would guess that carrying both happened at some volume because I don't see why else you'd have one pistol at home and another on your person?  In battles or in duels.  That's for 2 pistols and it actually underestimates when you carry 2 that are not a pair.  If you were fighting with guns and had the money to afford 2 guns, would you use this possibility?  Now, as to more than 2?  That's a whole lot more disputable.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: [Duelling pistols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duelling_pistol) *were* actually common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No. It wasn't common to carry multiple flintlock pistols.**

A flintlock pistol is heavy, single shot, highly inaccurate and expensive.

**Heavy:** this varied of course, but you can assume anything from 1 to 3 kg. If you carry two or more pistols, you'd be carrying a lot of useless weight. Blackbeard carried so many weapons not for self-defence, but simply to impress his victims.

A [Colt M1911](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1911_pistol) weighs 1100 grams.
An [average flintlock pistol](http://www.flintlocks.com/pistols.htm) from the 1800s weights about the same. That's two centuries of modifications and improvements later, or 400 years in case of the 1911.

**Highly inaccurate:** what do you miss on almost all flintlock weapons? Sights. A musket is already inaccurate as it lacks rifling, but it can (very limited) make up for it by having a longer barrel. A pistol lacks even that. No rifling, a round ball that comes out of a very short barrel, compared with a musket. You'd be lucky to hit a barn. Even if you stand inside one.

**Expensive:** Before the industrial revolution, firearms were handmade and consequently expensive. Guns were more commonly produced and less expensive. Pistols were far less in demand, and therefore more expensive.

@Pieter Geerkens is correct, some cavalry units used pistols as their primary weapon. However, they carried those heavy weapons in holsters on the saddle. Rarely on their person.

Those pistol armed cavalry units weren't that great. On the [Battle of the Mookerheyde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Mookerheyde) a German unit armed with pistols was defeated with ease by Spanish lancers when those Germans were reloading. *(Later in history, exactly the reverse happened.)*

In most cases, it was far more practical to carry something else than a pistol, let alone multiple pistols.

Comment: Interesting and logical answer, but it could use a little more references, e.g. for the 3 main claims.

Comment: You mention a "very short barrel" for the pistol but this is only in comparison with the muskets of the time (which had barrels 3-4ft long). A flintlock pistol barrel could be 10-12inches long, giving a weapon length of around 15-18 inches. So, not only heavy but cumbersome too.